# How to implement functions in a different classes in Java(testNG)

Tags: java, testng

I have a Java (testNG) program something like shown below. Now that the list of functions keeps growing, I want to implement each/setof functions in a separate java classes. What is the best approach to do this?

```
package myPackage;

import somepackages.*;

public class myClass {

  declare variable1;
  declare variable2;
  .
  .
  declare variableN;


  @BeforeTest(alwaysRun=true)
   public void beforeRun(){
   //do something
   }

  @Test
  public void test(){
    funtion1();
  }

  @AfterTest
  public void afterTest() {
   //do somthing
  }

  public void function1() {
  //calls function2, function3....
  }

  public void function2() {
  //do something
  }
  .
  .
  .
  .
  public void functionN() {
  //do something
  }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can extends the class from one to another and use the object of last created class...

```
public class myClass {
//some methods
}
public class myClass1 extends myClass {
//some another methods
}
public class myClass2 extends myClass1 {
//some another methods
}
```

Comment: I was looking something like to create base abstract class to declare all the methods and use different classes extending the abstract class for implementation. But not sure how to access the functions from my main class.. any idea on that?

Comment: in that case you have to add objects of one class into another

Comment: check my another answer

Comment: Ok Im keeping my base class non-abstract just defining all the methods with an empty body.(the sub classes extending this base class will do the implementation).Now from the main class i create a instance of the base class and how can I access the method implementations done by the subclasses? when i call the method it only executes the implementaion done(if any) in the base class. just want to conclude whether it can or cannot be done.

Comment: No it can not be done. how can you call the method of subclass from base class object!!!

Answer (score 0):

Test1.java

```
public abstract class Test1 {
    public abstract void fun1();
    public abstract void fun2();
    public abstract void fun3();
    public abstract void fun4();
}
```

Test2.java

```
public abstract class Test2 extends Test1 {

    @Override
    public void fun1() {
      //fun1 defination
    }

    @Override
    public void fun2() {
      //fun2 defination
    }
}
```

Test3.java

```
public class Test3 extends Test2 {

    @Override
    public void fun3() {
      //fun3 defination
    }

    @Override
    public void fun4() {
      //fun4 defination
    }
}
```

Test.java

```
public class Test{
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Test1 test = new Test3();
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I would like to know if its possible for all subclasses (test2,test3) to be extended from the same base class(test1).In that case all subclasses would be abstract classes. And from the main class, access any method from any class ?

Comment: If you extended all the subclass(test2,test3) from same base class(test1), in that case there are two ways- subclass need to implement all the abstract methods available in base class(test1) or class(test2,test3) become Abstract. You can not create the object of any abstract class.